# List manipulation to draw 3D graph (ndim - error)

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib, matrix

(This is not my actual problem, but I am modelling it in order to simplify the problem)

I have a two data-set which are not equal in size.

```
x_values = [1,2,3]
y_values = [4,5]
```

Let us suppose I have a function f, such that

```
def f(x,y):
    return x + y
```

What I want is, some sort of code such that takes each value from each array and creates (x,y) pairs

```
(1,4) , (1,5), (2,4), (2,5) , (3,4) ,(3,5)
```

and then puts them into the f where we obtain the z_values.

```
5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8
```

Now I want to draw a 3D plot in terms of all (x,y,z) coordinates, such that

```
(1,4,5) , (1,5,6), (2,4,6), (2,5,7) , (3,4,7) ,(3,5,8)
```

So I have to draw these points on 3D plot.

**EDIT: I solved the problem, but I am getting an Error when I try to draw a 3D graph**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1,2,3]
ys = [4,5]

def f(x,y):
    return x+y

A = list((x,y) for x in xs for y in ys)

New_points = []
for (x,y) in A:
    z = f(x,y)
    New_points.append((x,y,z))

    
X= list(New_points[i][0] for i in range(len(New_points)))
Y = list(New_points[i][1] for i in range(len(New_points)))
Z= list(New_points[i][2] for i in range(len(New_points)))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='b')
plt.show()
```

Error is:

```
line 1613, in plot_surface
if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

**Please help!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array

xs = [1,2,3]
ys = [4,5]

def f(x,y):
    return x+y

A = list((x,y) for x in xs for y in ys)

New_points = []
for (x,y) in A:
    z = f(x,y)
    New_points.append((x,y,z))

    
X= list(New_points[i][0] for i in range(len(New_points)))
Y = list(New_points[i][1] for i in range(len(New_points)))
Z= list(New_points[i][2] for i in range(len(New_points)))

Z = array(Z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

This works

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you only need `plot_surface`:

```
Z = f(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
```

**Update**: For generic function:

```
xs = [1,2,3]
ys = [4,5]

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

Z = np.array([[f(x,y) for y in ys] for x in xs])

ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. However, I noticed that when I take X and Y as an arrays and put into my original function, I get an error. So the problem is I need to pass single values(elements) for each X and Y and not as an array

Comment: @Layla i would write a separate question asking for help in vectorizing your function. there's a good chance it doesn't need to be applied element-wise

Comment: @Okay..that would be nice

Comment: @Layla my code was for `X,Y = np.meshgrid(xs,ys)` and `def f(x,y): return x+y`. You seemed to have that `meshgrid` at first. Not sure why you removed it from your updated question.

Comment: @QuangHoang My code was giving error for using an array inside the function. I need to pass single value one at a time..

Comment: @QuangHoang I saw an error                                                                                                           
             File "c:/Users/Arman/Desktop/Cosmology/Masters/gDE/test.py", line 21, in 
             <module>
             ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
             File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
        packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", 
      line 1613, in plot_surface
    if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: And what is meshgridh ?

Comment: @QuangHoang again error...ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape